# React 5 second timer crashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand what my mistake is. I'm using `setInterval` within `useEffect` with `[]` dependency that updates the `ms` (milliseconds) state by adding 1 to it every 10 milliseconds. I have a `time()` function that is responsible for updating `ms` and `secs` state and also for stopping and displaying the timer. Once the timer reaches 5 seconds, `done` state is set to `true`, the interval is cleared and the timer should stop. But instead it crashes with this error: "*Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop*". Why does this happen and how do I fix it? Here's the code link https://codepen.io/Montinyek/pen/zYLzBZP?editors=1111

```
function App() {
  const [secs, setSecs] = React.useState(0);
  const [ms, setMs] = React.useState(0);
  const [done, setDone] = React.useState(false)
  
  let id = React.useRef()
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    id.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (!done) {
        setMs(prev => prev += 1)
      } 
}, 10);
    return () => clearInterval(id.current);
  }, [])
  
  function time() {
    if (ms === 100) {
    setMs(0)
    setSecs(prev => prev += 1)
    }
    if (secs === 5) {
    clearInterval(id.current)
    setDone(true)
    }
    let formattedSecs = secs < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs;
    let formattedMils = ms < 10 ? "0" + ms : ms;
    return `${formattedSecs} : ${formattedMils}`;
  }

  return <div>{time()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: On every update, you have a new render. On every render you create a new interval within `useEffect()`. After 5 seconds you have create 5000(?) intervals, but only stopped one. The others keep on a runnin'

Comment: But why does a new interval keep being created if the dependency is []? Shouldn't it run only once?

Comment: Editing render to be `<div>{!done && time()}</div>` will call `time()` if `done` === `false`. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works. If you're not already using `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`, I recommend installing

Comment: Even if that works, its probably a bad idea. Calling anything that could potentially set state in render is asking for trouble and also and indicator the solution is incorrectly modelled.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the function `time()` in *render* and that function is making calls to set state. Generally, you should never set state in render or you get into a loop situation when you render, the state is set (which triggers a rerender), then state is set again, then it rerenders, and so on.

Your problem isn't actually that new intervals are being created. It's actually unrelated entirely to the timer ticks in a way. The problem is that when it reaches 5 seconds, it gets into a "render loop".

Specifically what happens in your case is this:

1. The timer hits 5 seconds.
2. Render calls `time()`
3. `clearInterval(id.current)` is called and also `setDone(true)`. The set operation here causes another render.
4. Render calls `time()`.
5. Back to (3).

You need to encapsulate the logic that sets the state in the interval handler, and not make your logic intrinsically linked to render passes. However, this is one of the more complicated things in react (handling state in an interval) since you can get into all sorts of problems with recalling stale state. To understand my answer, you will need to read Dan Abramov's (a key React contributor) [article about this](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/). I have lifted the `useInterval` hook from his blog.

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = React.useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

function App() {
  const [secs, setSecs] = React.useState(0);
  const [ms, setMs] = React.useState(0);
 
  
  useInterval(() => {
      if (ms >= 100) {
        setMs(0)
        setSecs(prev => prev + 1)
        return
      }

      setMs(prev => prev + 1)
  }, secs < 5 ? 10 : null)
  
  function getFormattedTime() {
    let formattedSecs = secs < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs;
    let formattedMils = ms < 10 ? "0" + ms : ms;
    return `${formattedSecs} : ${formattedMils}`;
  }
 

  return <div>{getFormattedTime()}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Note that the render now only calls `getFormattedTime` which does not touch the state.

When refactoring this I found `done` wasn't needed since `useInterval` supports conditionally stopping the interval easily by passing a variable tickrate: `secs < 5 ? 10 : null`. `null` means "stopped".

Comment: Thank you, could you please take a look at this solution also and explain how it works? I don't understand the use of dependencies here and how they make the timer stop. Specifically, why does leaving an empty array dependency instead of [done] prevent the timer from stopping? https://codepen.io/Montinyek/pen/NWBvGqZ

Comment: Right, yeh this is the other way of solving it. The reason you have to add them in the deps with this solution is because if you do not, the `setInterval` inside the effects holds stale references to the ms/secs state from the first render pass. Without it in deps, they'd always be read as 0. This is one of the gotchas of intervals and react (explained in the blog in my answer). Essentially, in react, it is bad practice to read from state without adding that state to the deps array. `useInterval` tends to be more ergonomic to read.

Comment: In your alternative solution, every millisecond that passes will actually remove the interval (` return () => clearInterval(interval);`) and then set it again. You are actually clearing down and creating the timer 5000 times in that solution. Which actually isn't as bad as it sounds, but it may cause some drift.